# Is there a collections addAll utility method that will ensure that the underlying data structure of the collection is only resized at most once?

Tags: java, collections

The implementation of the addAll method in java.util.Collections simply loops through the source collection and calls the add method of the receiving collection for each element in the source collection.

Thus, resizing of the receiving collection's underlying data structure could occur multiple times if the capacity of the receiving collection is small and we are adding many elements to it. Each resize will be an O(n) operation.

It seems that a good collections addAll method should exist that will check the number of elements we will be adding and set the capacity of the receiving collection once at the beginning (if necessary). Does such a utility method exist? And if not, why not?

**Clarification:** I realize that there are implementation specific addAll methods (as in ArrayList) that have this desired behavior. I am wondering if there are Collection utility classes that will get me this behavior in a way that works across all Collection implementation classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a utility method cannot exists for a generic `Collection`, because the necessary method `ensureCapacity(int)` is not in any interface but only on implementations which have some benefit for that. Currently this are `ArrayList`, `BitSet` and `Vector`. Both `ArrayList` and `Vector` *have* adjusted `addAll` methods. `BitSet` is something completely different :-)

Answer (score 8):

About which collection are you specifcally talking about? I see that e.g. `ArrayList` does the following:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacity(size + numNew);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    //...
}
```

Which seems like exactly your desired behaviour.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am talking about. This works fine for ArrayList, but I was wondering if there is a Collections utility class that will have an addAll method that only resizes once that will work for all Collections.

From the answers, it seems that such a utility method cannot exist because the Collection implementations differ so much from one another.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific collection implementation.

For example for a ArrayList it will increase the array size once. And usually it doubles the size so doing 10 calls not always requires 10 new array creation.

But for LinkedList it just need to append to the end each element. Something that will be very fast to do.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by your clarification, because `Collection.addAll` *is* the method you seem to be asking for.

Comment: No. The java.util.Collections.addAll could end up resizing the underlying data structure more than once if a large number of objects are being added to a collection with a small initial capacity. That is the behavior I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding. I said `Collection.addAll`, not `Collections.addAll`, for one thing. This lets the implementation class do the best thing it knows how to do. How are you going to get better than that?